# Why this submit all form code isn't working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code below is colouring the input but not submitting the form in chrome. It's working in Firefox:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
    $('input').keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == '13') {
    //alert($(this).parentsUntil('form').css('color'));
    $('form').css('color','red');
    $('form').submit();
    }
    });});</script>
```

Please note that the submit button is set to display:none, if I change it to visibility:hidden, it works but it reserve the place which is not what I want.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Here's a full example as requested below:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.7/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
<title>دخول</title> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(function(){
    $('input').keypress(function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            $(this).parents('form').submit();
        }
    });
});
</script> 
</head> 
<body> 
<form action="http://www.yahoo.com" method='post'> 
<table > 
<tr><td>name: </td><td><input type="text" name="username" value=""></td></tr> 

<tr><td>password: </td><td><input type="password" name="password" value=""></td></tr> 
<tr><td colspan=2><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="$('#loginfrm').click();">Login</a> 
<div style="display: none;"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" id="loginfrm"></div></td></tr> 
</table> 
</form>
```

Comment: Your code works for me as is with a simple example. Can we see a full working example with HTML markup?

Comment: BTW, did you know you can indent JavaScript code? ;-P

Comment: change `event.keyCode` to `event.which`, `keyCode` is not fully cross browser compatible.

Comment: The full code is attached now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your problem is that you named your submit button `submit`, the browser sees that as a used name, give the submit button a name like `dosubmit` or whatever and it works.

with name `submit` (does not work)

http://www.jsfiddle.net/pVUwW/

with name `dosubmit` (works)

http://www.jsfiddle.net/pVUwW/1/

the only difference in those is the name of the submit.
Other than that i changed the `event.keyCode` to `event.which` from your original code, see http://api.jquery.com/event.which/ for explanation why.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to provide the examples. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

This is strange, just tried this in Chrome, it works correctly even without your code (`keypress`)

http://jsfiddle.net/72Nbm/

Comment: I don't see any action in your example, make sure you click "Run" to test your code.